# Cant change user quota on xfs partition

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, xfs, quota

I cant change user quota even command exit status is 0.

Used:

```
 xfs_quota -x -c 'limit bsoft=1024m bhard=2048m  56a4d3057ec81767ebe0415b' /
```

Also used webmin interface to update user quota but on both cases user quota is not changed.

[image: enter code here]

```
 xfs_quota -xc 'report' /
User ID          Used       Soft       Hard    Warn/Grace
---------- --------------------------------------------------
56a4d3057ec81767ebe0415b      23568          0          0     00 [--------]
```

[image]

Here is the mount point info:

```
 mount | grep ' / '
/dev/sda1 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,usrquota)
```

**UPDATE**
Actually quota is working for standard users but not for users who are chrooted with jailkit.

Any tips?

Comment: I admit I have little knowledge of cPanel, but are you certain it is are of xfs_quotas vs quotas set with the quota package?  Is the actual mount option set `uquota` or `gquota` per [the xfs man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/xfs_quota) ?  I tested it myself and uquota will translate to a mount option of usrquota which is confusing at best.

Comment: @Aaron i followed this tutorial http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=557